# Regex Puzzle: How to replace dumb quotes with smart ones

Tags: javascript, regex, quotes

Dumb quote are those that show up straight. Smart quotes curl and they curl in the right direction.  I believe the rules are as follows:

- If the quote is at the start of a word it curls right.
- If the quote is at the start of a word proceeded by another quote or grouping symbol ({[ it curls right.
- If a quote is anywhere else it curls left.

I need some script that takes a variable holding a string and replaces all the straight quotes with correctly curling ones.

[This](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) has the relevant resources for the various character codes.

```
var replacedText = text.replace(/"(?=[a-zA-Z])/gi,"\u201C");
var replacedText = replacedText.replace(/'(?=[a-zA-Z])/gi,"\u2018");
```

For example, the above works in terms of syntax and I imagine a well structured series of replacements could work.  But I'm struggling to get the logic right.  Since I want to replace both single and double quotes and I want to replace them intelligently, such that they "open" and "close" in the right direction.

Comment: Examples with their desired output if you may!

Comment: Its hard to give an example because SO converts all quotes to dumb quotes.  But the goal should be clear enough from the question.

Comment: What are `dumb quotes` and `smart quotes`???

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it is clearly explained in the first two sentences of the question and a commonly used term

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a starting point?  What I did here is basically just assume a space before the first quotation mark OR if the quotation mark is at the beginning of the string is the start of a "quote" message.  Then I move through until there's a closing quotation mark.  Again, just a start. Not sure if this qualifies all those things you mentioned:

```
var sample = 'One guy walks into a bar and says, "Dude, whaddup?".';

sample.replace(/(\s|^)\"([^\"]+)\"/g, "$1\u201C$2\u201D")
// should return: One guy walks into a bar and says, “Dude, whaddup?”.

var sample2 = '"E=mc2" is Eistein\'s signature';

sample2.replace(/(\s|^)\"([^\"]+)\"/g, "$1\u201C$2\u201D")
// should return: “E=mc2” is Eistein's signature.
```

I'll explain this in more detail, I guess, for learning sake...

`(\s|^)\"` is capturing any space OR beginning of string then a quotation mark

`([^\"])+` capturing any character that is NOT a quote (assuming everything in between the quotation marks in the string.

`\"` is the ending quotation mark

Then I placed smart quotation marks with the captured middle string and voila! Hope that helps!

Comment: This works great for double quotes.  But single ones are a bit trickier.  Any ideas on how best to identify either stand alone pairs of single quotes and convert them as you have done AND handle quotes used as intra-word apostrophes as in "can't"

Comment: @COMisHARD So i would assume that in cases like "can't" then you just need to replace all the apostrophes that come after a letter to be a closing single quote and never the opposite right?  In that case I chain another `replace`.  So something like this ```.replace(/([A-Za-z])\'/g, "$1\u2019")```... By the way, if you are converting single quote quotes, you should chain that `replace` clause AFTER this clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const str = `HELLO, LOOK "AT" YOU!`;
const str1 = `HELLO, LOOK 'AT' YOU!`;

const straightToCurly = (str) => {
  return str
    .replace(/"(.*?)"/g, function (wholematch, singlematch) {
      return "“" + singlematch + "”";
    })
    .replace(/'(.*?)'/g, function (wholematch, singlematch) {
      return "‘" + singlematch + "’";
    });
};

console.log("Result: ", straightToCurly(str));
console.log("Result: ", straightToCurly(str1));
```